# Why can't I see the bottom of my F3 thing in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press F3 it only shows chunk-relative and up. How do I get the bottom back?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot to help visualize what it looks like now?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. (Current position and etc not showing up) But next time, please explain what behavior you expected was. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193496/x-y-z-missing-in-f3

Comment: Woop... You beat me to it @QbsidianH20... That one has been answered now Ashleigh so go ahead and read off of it.