# How do I turn co-ordinates on in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Windows 7 PC, and I think it has something to do with the F3 key. I don't have the Fn (function) key, I tried pressing F3 with all the keys I have, and have had no luck.

Comment: Do you get any information at all when you press f3?

Comment: Do you have an f lock key?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to press the function key (fn) if you have little functions assigned to the keys themselves:

**For Example**

I have a brightness up on my F3 key, but I need to press fn+F3 to use it, but this does not affect my controls when playing Minecraft or any other action that requires the use of F3.

When in doubt, never forget there's a [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com).

[This link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193496/x-y-z-missing-in-f3?lq=1) may help as well.