# How do I display the chunk borders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't display the chunk borders, even if I hit <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. How do I get them to show up?

Comment: Using any mods? On a server?

Comment: No, I don't use mods

Comment: This has never worked for me in optifine 1.8.8. Is that what you were using?

Answer (score 9):

I know that sometimes you need to hold down the function key (<kbd>Fn</kbd> on most keyboards) for the <kbd>F</kbd> keys to work. Try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: No its Not That It says "Chuck borders: shown", I have Reset My Computer And Minecraft, and it doesn't Show Up. Please help me!

Answer (score 8):

Go into chat settings and disable reduced debug info.
It should re-enable the following:

- Chunk borders
- Bounding boxes
- Coordinates
- Block info
- Chunk info.
- Facing info.
- Client and server light info.
- Biome info.
- Sound info.
- Difficulty info.

And probably more.

[Source](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193496/x-y-z-missing-in-f3)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It actually solved it for me.

Comment: Wow, I am so glad I finally looked this up because I would never have considered displaying the boundaries of chunks in game to be controlled by something in chat settings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the lock key on. Try unlocking it by pressing fn + lock key (esc key) and then pressing fn + f + 3

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I had this problem today and I couldn't find the answer easily. The problem is while pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> it doesn't understand the <kbd>G</kbd>, so while pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> release the <kbd>fn</kbd> then press <kbd>G</kbd>, it worked for me, I hope it works for whoever lands on this post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the MC devs (Dinnerbone) has an online tool that allows you to calculate chunks.
https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/

Answer (score 0):

The lines of the chunk border appear virtually invisible when running shaders. Simply, turn off your shaders if you're running them

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be the thing causing the issue:
A broken keyboard. I used to play Minecraft on my laptop and the function keys didn't work. Make sure that your keyboard is working.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't just supposed to be holding `Fn`? If it's a laptop then probably. You're just using your keyboard wrong; it's not broken.

Answer (score -1):

On some computers, it is just <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> but on mine is an HP and I use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>