# I have optifine with forge and turn off debug but I don't see my x, y and z coordinates in my f3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason, I can't see my coordinates in my F3 console. Here's a link of the photo. Please help me because I just wanted to see my coordinates in case I get lost in caves or something.

[image: 1]

Comment: thats because your looking in the wrong part of the f3 menu

Comment: `/gamerule reducedDebugInfo false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X,Y,Z missing in F3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193496/x-y-z-missing-in-f3)

Comment: @F4D I don't think that's the issue, I think that's separate

Answer (score 8):

You are looking in the wrong spot. Here it is:
[image: Debug]