# I can't see my coordinates and light level when I press F3 on my friend's smp

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I tried searching it up but I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't show the coordinates and light level.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Also, this link may be relevant https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193496/x-y-z-missing-in-f3.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per kusobito's comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely your friend has turned on the gamerule `reducedDebugInfo`, this gamerule will hide coordinates and reduced lightlevel. See [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen#Legend) wiki page for more info.